# Procedure or function x has too many arguments specified

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

I have a gridview with the following SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnString%>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT IDC, DESCPREVIEW, ADESCPREVIEW, DESC, ADESC, DATETOs, Active, HAVEIMG FROM CONTENT ORDER BY IDC DESC "
            UpdateCommand="[SP_UPDATE_CONTENT]" 
            UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="IDC" Type="Int32" />
               <asp:Parameter Name="DESCPREVIEW" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DESC" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DATETOs" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="active" Type="Boolean" />
            </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The Stored procedure has these parameters defined:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UPDATE_CONTENT]

@IDC AS INT,
@DESCPREVIEW AS NVARCHAR(800),
@DESC  AS NVARCHAR(1500),
@DATETOs AS VARCHAR(10),
@active as bit
```

I am getting the following error on Update:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function SP_UPDATE_CONTENT has too many arguments specified.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753346
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5295154
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +269
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1325
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +175
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +205
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +380
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues) +670
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +87
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +1210
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +738
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +89
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +88
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +121
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +156
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9643314
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Although these are the same exact parameters

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

Apparently the Update Command considered all the Selected fields in the SelectCommand as parameters.

So I minimized the selectCommand to the needed number of fields only.

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT IDC, DESCPREVIEW, DESC, DATETOs, Active FROM CONTENT ORDER BY IDC DESC "
```